# Gesture detection coordinates not synced with viewport

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to implement pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) from GestureDetector  .
I set the coordinates of the texture to the parameters of the pan , so whenever i drag the texture
on screen it draws there . it worked perfectly .

> Now i put a camera and a viewport in the screen and suddenly the the
>   texture isn't following the drag coordinates properly .

here is the create() method where I initialise my camera and viewport

```
    @Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    pos = new Vector2(0,0);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.position.set(width/2,height/2,0);
    viewport = new StretchViewport(width,height,camera);
    viewport.apply();
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gestureDetector);
}
```

and here is how i implement the pan method from the interface

```
@Override
public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    pos.x = x ;
    pos.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y ;
    return true;
}
```

The code works fine when i am touching the top left corner of the screen
where the Gesture detector considers the coordinate (0,0) but as I drift towards 
the right ,the texture drawn is somewhat ahead of the x coordinate being touched  . 
It is working fine with respect to the Y axis .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent checked what you are trying to achieve but if you say it worked fine before you added a camera and viewport then it probably has something to do with screen vs world coordinates.

I believe what you are looking for is `viewport.unproject()` or `camera.unproject()`, this will transform screen coordinates into world coordinates and it should work properly.

Addition:

> `unproject(Vector3 screenCoords)`
>     Function to translate a point given in screen coordinates to world space.

source: [Libgdx Camera Doc](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html)

Comment: I tried looking around about unprojecting but I am unable to get my head around it , It would be a huge help if you can please direct me to some resource or tell me how to use it and where .
As I understand it , the screen is a part of the world we have shown as viewport using the camera ( by the projection matrix of the camera ) .
-> difference between the screen and world coordinates ? 
any help is thoroughly appreciated :)

Comment: @satyamsinghal I added some stuff to help you out. Basically you feed it your screen coordinates in Vector format and it will spit out a translated vector which will have the correct world coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

pos.add(deltax, -deltay) ;

X and y are current mouse position. Delta is how much it has been dragged.